# Magento 2 : How to save swatch_text attribute options programatically?

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, swatches

I'm creating a product attribute with input type 'swatch_text'.

But I'm able to save option value but swatch text value is not saving.

Can anyone help me in saving the marked field in screenshot programatically?

I am using below code :

```
    $option = [
        'values' => [ 'X','Y','Z'
        ],
        'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
    ];       
    $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($option);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, is there any solution for this?

Comment: No solution found. Changed reuirement

Comment: It is fixed in Magento version 2.3. Also, I found this link. It might help others.
Found this solution[https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18114/files] from here[https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18057]